# QuickStart Guide Fail - AZ3166 Can't Connect to Azure IoT Hub

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I have the MxChip IoT DevKit and have followed the step-by-step instructions at this page, [Quickstart: Send telemetry from DevKit to an IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-arduino-iot-devkit-az3166-get-started#quickstart-send-telemetry-from-devkit-to-an-iot-hub).

Reality departs from the guide in the **Send DevKit telemetry** section. At step 8, the IoT DevKit does indeed reboot and does show an allocated IP address so my WiFi LED is green. However, it stops at this point. The last message on the DevKit is "Running...   > IoT Hub". It does not progress to show telemetry data and the Azure LED is not lit up.

I'm not sure where the block is. Is my BT Router blocking (less likely), are there missing steps in the guide (very likely)?

Would really approeciate some help...

Comment: Can you reset and try again **'Send DevKit telemetry section'**, Could you please confirm that your WIFi is 2.4GHz network. Please verify the IoTHub device connection string is correct.

Comment: Yes. WiFi 2.4GHz. Tried the section again, now I can't connect to the IoT DevKit. Connection string was cut and past and transfered to machine via data stick. Still not able to progress.

Comment: Can you confirm that your Device connection string is in this format, HostName={YourIoTHubName}.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=MyNodeDevice;SharedAccessKey={YourSharedAccessKey}, Just wanted to make sure that you have copied the device connection string and not the IoTHub connection string.

Comment: Yes. The correct string was supplied.

Comment: Please try [Upgrade the bootloader for IoT DevKit](https://microsoft.github.io/azure-iot-developer-kit/docs/firmware-upgrading/)

Comment: Okay, I've done that. When done, only the power light is on. No programming LED, blank display. Pressed the reset button to see what happens. Message is "Initializing Wi-Fi" for a few seconds, then display goes blank and nothing happens.

Comment: A power-cycle produces much the same result except the programming light stays on.

Comment: Okay, got it to boot by following instructions on "quick" start guide. On a laptop I'm connected to the device's AP. But entering "192.168.0.1" into Firefox gives me a timeout. What can I do now. My 30-day free trial will run out before I get this to work.

Comment: I disconnected from the AP and clicked Connect again. Now I get "Unable to connect to this network" The device is sitting right next to my laptop.

Comment: Okay, I've reset everything, started fresh sessions and I can get the device to display "IoT DevKit  Current: 1.6.5  Latest: 1.6.5    Btn B: Sensors". The RGB LED is cycling through R, G, B. Wi-Fi is green, Azure is off, User is flashing amber. What next? IoT Hub Cloud Shell shows no events being detected.

Comment: Could you please let me know when will your free trial ends? and have you tried to connect to DevKit from another computers' chrome or edge browser?

Comment: I suspect the device fails to connect to Azure because the IP address it is using is 10.0.0.215 - my private in-house WiFi network. What button do I press to run analyse my network architecture and advise me on how to connect to Azure?

Comment: Expires in 25 days.

Comment: No need to use another browser - we're past that stage now.

Comment: Now the device fails to connect to Azure, otherwise it appears to be sensing.

Comment: ok, so i just tried it on my  new Devkit device with latest firmware, please confirm if you are able to see the **IoT Device Connection String** text box when you browse 192.168.01.1 ?

Comment: Please make sure that you have followed these steps 1) Update the Firmware with file name 'devkit-firmware-1.6.5.bin' added to device 2) Added the 'devkit-getstarted-1.6.5.bin' file to device, put it in AP mode, then connected via browser and able to configure WiFi password, and device connection string.

Comment: I have downloaded the very latest firmware i do NOT see the IoT Device Connection String text box when you browse 192.168.0.1 - are the instructions wrong. should I try 192.168.1.1?

Comment: I've made sure the network credentials are valid and it should have direct access to the internet. The IP address displayed is 192.168.1.66 - would this be normal?

Comment: You have completed the First step of Firmware update, now Please make sure the second step to complete 2) Added the [devkit-getstarted-1.6.5.bin](https://aka.ms/devkit/prod/getstarted/latest) file to device, put it in AP mode, then connected via browser and able to configure WiFi password, and device connection string. When you put the device in AP mode the ip address is visible on the screen, you have to use it in the browser.

Comment: I have done this 4 times. I don't understand the second step - what your saying is do the same thing again?

Comment: I've downloaded that 1.6.5 file four times! I've followed the instructions. Are they wrong? Are you telling me there is a work around?

Comment: First step is Firmware file and second step is getStarted file.

Comment: You have to add Firmware file in first step and then download the getstarted project sample file as a second step, both are 2 different files.

Comment: When you download, the each files has its own name, so please don't be confused in that.

Comment: I don't feel confused. The guide is quite clear - (and wrong) - it says in section 8 of the "Send DevKit telemetry" section... "On the DevKit screen, you see the IP address for the DevKit follows by the telemetry data including temperature and humidity value with message count send to Azure IoT Hub". I see the IP number (192.168.1.66), but no telemetry data.

Comment: We see that you have posted the same issue on [Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/56496). Please send us an email at azcommunity@microsoft.com, so that we can work closely on this matter. 
**Thread URL:** Link to this thread.
**Azure Subscription ID: **
**Subject :** Attn Satish Boddu 
Please let me know once you have done the same